# Backup and Restore MySQL Database in Spring Data (JAVA)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-data

Is there an easy way to backup and restore database in Spring Data?

Comment: I think this would be DB-specific.  In MySQL, I believe there is a command called mysqldump to dump a copy of a given DB to a file.

Comment: Yes. mysqldump. But I was hoping there is a config in spring data to automate this.

Comment: No, there is not.  At least not any that I know of.  If you are looking for something auto-magic, I would suggest looking into replication.

Comment: There isn't. spring-data does not provide such tools. only option in case of mysql is what @CodeChimp said. **mysqldump**.   the good news is that mysqldump is pretty simple to use.

Comment: @YoniMoses and fast, from what I remember.